# Protection of Firebase + Raspberry Pi infrastructure

Tags: android, firebase, security, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm creating a system that will be on a public site and will use firebase + raspberry pi + android, there will be several machines and they will all share services.

The problem is that the machine being in a public place and being using raspberry pi the code will not be encrypted and can be accessed by extracting the sd card.

I do not care if they can see the code, I will try to centralize what I can in the cloud and seal in some way the raspberry, what worries me is that being the configuration files of firebase in the raspberry pi someone can access and use them to do something that should not, for example consult / modify / delete private data in the database of that machine or other.

Any ideas to protect these services and/or the code that is in the raspberry pi and add more security to this infrastructure?

Regards.